# TPKeyboardAvoiding scrollview defaults to wrong return key type 'Done' in iOS not UIReturnKeyNext

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, tpkeyboardavoiding

I have used this keyboard avoiding library https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding in many iOS projects.It works as expected but in a project it is producing a weird issue where return key title is always 'Done' instead of 'Next'.Functionality is still correct like tapping on keyboard 'Done' is making the below UITextField first responder and Tapping the last keyboard 'Done' is resigning the keyboard.
I have used it many iOS versions and both Objective-C and swift projects without any issue 
Currently using xcode 8.3.2 with swift
Anyone have similar issue or know the reason for this issue.
[[image: First Field returnKey is 'Done']]]

Comment: Hello @Waseem05
Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the github page:

"To disable the automatic "Next" button functionality, change the UITextField's return key type to anything but UIReturnKeyDefault."

This could be the reason for your problem.

Comment: We want the 'Next' button functionality to work and it is working but not changing the uireturnkeyType  to UIReturnKeyNext

Comment: I have never used this, but i would go inside the subclasses and debug the process where the next key functionality is implemented. Or you could manually try to change the uireturnkeytype if that would work.